# Parsing an Expression in the form <id> = <expr>

Tags: parsing

When the program runs it asks me to write an expression to be parsed but when I type anything, I get this:

```
Enter an expression to be parsed below:
read * 3 

Call lex...read
Enter <program>
Enter <statement>
Call lex...
ERROR: Must be of the form <id> = <expr>.
```

Here is the program:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int charClass;
char lexeme[100];
char nextChar;
int lexemeLength;
int token;
int nextmaiToken;
int i = 0;
string input;
int lex ();
void program ();
void statement ();
void expr ();
void term ();
void factor ();

#define LETTER 0
#define NUMBER 1
#define UNKNOWN 99
#define INT_CONSTANT 10
#define ID 11
#define ASSIGNMENT_OP 20
#define ADD_OP 21
#define SUB_OP 22
#define MULT_OP 23
#define DIV_OP 24
#define LEFT_PAREN 25
#define RIGHT_PAREN 26
#define EQUALS 27
#define END -1

void
addChar ()
{
  if (lexemeLength <= 98)
    {
      lexeme[lexemeLength++] = nextChar;
      lexeme[lexemeLength] = 0;
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "Error - lexeme is too long!\n\n";
      exit (1);
    }
}

void
getChar ()
{
  nextChar = input[i++];
  if (nextChar != END)
    {
      if (isalpha (nextChar))
    charClass = LETTER;
      else if (isdigit (nextChar))
    charClass = NUMBER;
      else
    charClass = UNKNOWN;
    }
  else
    charClass = END;
}

void
getNonBlank ()
{
  if (isspace (nextChar))
    getChar ();
}

int lookup (char ch)
{
  switch (ch)
    {
    case '(':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = LEFT_PAREN;
      break;
    case ')':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = RIGHT_PAREN;
      break;
    case '+':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = ADD_OP;
      break;
    case '-':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = SUB_OP;
      break;
    case '*':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = MULT_OP;
      break;
    case '/':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = DIV_OP;
      break;
    case ';':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = END;
      break;
    case '=':
      addChar ();
      nextmaiToken = EQUALS;
      break;
    default:
      addChar ();
      break;
    }
  return nextmaiToken;
}

int lex ()
{
  lexemeLength = 0;
  switch (charClass)
    {
    case LETTER:
      addChar ();
      getChar ();
      while (charClass == LETTER || charClass == NUMBER)
    {
      addChar ();
      getChar ();
    }
      nextmaiToken = ID;
      break;
    case NUMBER:
      addChar ();
      getChar ();
      while (charClass == NUMBER)
    {
      addChar ();
      getChar ();
    }
      nextmaiToken = INT_CONSTANT;
      break;
    case UNKNOWN:
      lookup (nextChar);
      getChar ();
      break;
    default:
      nextmaiToken = END;
      lexeme[0] = 'E';
      lexeme[1] = 'O';
      lexeme[2] = 'F';
      break;
    }
  cout << "Call lex..." << lexeme << "\n";
  return nextmaiToken;
}

void program ()
{
  cout << "Enter <program>\n";
  statement ();
  if (nextmaiToken != END)
    {
      cout << "ERROR: No ending ';'\n\n";
      exit (1);
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "Exit <program>\n";
      cout << "This is a valid program.\n\n";
    }
}

void statement ()
{
  cout << "Enter <statement>\n";
  if (nextmaiToken == ID)
    {
      lex ();
      if (nextmaiToken == EQUALS)
    {
      lex ();
      expr ();
    }
      else
    {
      cout << "ERROR: Must be of the form <id> = <expr>.\n\n";
      exit (1);
    }
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "ERROR: Must be of the form <id> = <expr>.\n\n";
      exit (1);
    }
  cout << "Exit <statement>\n";
}

void expr ()
{
  cout << "Enter <expr>\n";
  term ();
  while (nextmaiToken == ADD_OP || nextmaiToken == SUB_OP)
    {
      lex ();
      term ();
    }
  cout << "Exit <expr>\n";
}

void term ()
{
  cout << "Enter <term>\n";
  factor ();
  while (nextmaiToken == MULT_OP || nextmaiToken == DIV_OP)
    {
      lex ();
      factor ();
    }
  cout << "Exit <term>\n";
}

void factor ()
{
  cout << "Enter <factor>\n";
  if (nextmaiToken == ID || nextmaiToken == INT_CONSTANT)   //for the cases: <factor> -> id and <factor> -> int_constant
    lex ();
  else
    {
      if (nextmaiToken == LEFT_PAREN)   //for the case: <factor> -> ( <expr> )
    {
      lex ();
      expr ();
      if (nextmaiToken == RIGHT_PAREN)  //must close parentheses
        lex ();
      else
        {
          cout << "ERROR: No closing parentheses.\n\n";
          exit (1);
        }
    }
      else
    {
      cout << "ERROR: Unbalanced expression.\n\n";
      exit (1);
    }
    }
  cout << "Exit <factor>\n";
}

int main ()
{
  cout << "\nEnter an expression:\n";
  cin >> input;
  cout << "\n";
  nextChar = input[i];
  getChar ();
  lex ();
  program ();
  return (1);
}
```

The possible set of tokens, represented with regular expressions, includes:
= + - * /  ( )
ID  -> letter(letter|digit)*
Except read, write, and halt.
LETTER      ->[a-zA-Z]
DIGIT       ->[0-9]

What is missing or what is making stop early!!

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. It's expecting a statement of the form `<id> = <expr>`, such as `a = 3`. The grammar also allows `read <id>` (eg. `read a`) and `write <expr>` (eg. `write a * 3`). What you typed doesn't match any of those patterns.

Comment: @rici I tried that before and it didnt work

Comment: If that's your code, I guess you [need to debug it](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you expect anyone else to read it, make it readable by indenting it consistently and getting rid of the unnecessary double-spacing.

Comment: Assuming `read * 3` is your input, then looking at the `void statement ()` function makes it pretty clear to see that you get the error because your syntax requires a `=` for a statement to be valid, which isn't present in the input.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I used other statements with and without `=` sign and I still had the same issue

Comment: Then update the question with those as well, please.